# Hibernate get all foreign keys for mapped entities

Tags: java, hibernate

i need to get the column names for foreign keys for all mapped hibernate entities. Does anyone know how to do that?
I tried by sessionFactory.getClassMetadata - i can see all the properties names and types for all entities there, but i cannot find information about foreign keys.
Does anyone have any idea? I may not use direct database query - i must extract it from hibernate metadata.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329588/how-do-i-get-name-of-the-target-table-and-column-of-foreign-key-column-with-plai

Comment: this is not suitable. jdbc.getConnectionMetadata will return DATABASE relations, and i need strictly jpa relations (for example some of the foreign keys may not be created on db yet)

Comment: `Table.getForeignKeyIterator()` should find all foreign keys for a table. If I remember correctly you can retrieve them from `EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.getHibernateConfiguration().getTableMappings()`

Comment: Tobias, unfortunatelly Table.getForeignKeyIterator() returns only keys that are physically existing in database. And i need the keys from the entity mapping -  java code (annotation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Reflection:

```
// Loop through joined columns that has @JoinColumn annotation
for (Method method : testClass.getMethods())
{
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(JoinColumn.class))
    {
         // name parameter is foreign key
         String foreignKey = method.getAnnotation(JoinColumn.class).name;

         // if the referencedColumnName is explicitly defined
         String foreignKey = method.getAnnotation(JoinColumn.class).referencedColumnName;
    }
}
```