# Hibernate - @JoinTable - extract foreign keys via classMetaData

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ATTACHMENTS")
public class Attachment{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String attachmentUsername;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "ATT_DOC",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_DOC", referencedColumnName = "ID")
            },
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ATT", referencedColumnName = "ID")
            })
            private Set<Document> documents = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I have an entity mapped like ^^^^. The relation between attachment and document is @ManyToMany. I need to extract the foreign keys (the exact names of the columns) on runtime. Unfortunatelly i may not user any database queries nor database metadata (like connection.getMetaData).
    I may only user hibernate sessionFactory().getAllClassMetadata

So i have metadata of every mapped entity (plenty of properties like subclassPropertyTypeClosure, subclassPropertyNameClosure ...). But i cannot find any information about foreign keys for jointable. Anyone had similar problem?
    Thanks in advance

Comment: Same question posted by the same user on the same day: [Hibernate get all foreign keys for mapped entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995579/hibernate-get-all-foreign-keys-for-mapped-entities)

Comment: Its not the same - this question concerns only on reading annotation info for @JoinTable